# MySQL command to get first letter of last name

Tags: mysql

[image]Hello I have made a dummy table that I am practicing with and I am trying to get the lasts name first letter for example. Aba Kadabra and Alfa Kadabra the last letter of their last name is 'K' so when I was testing some queries such as...

```
select * from employees
where full_name like 'K%'

select * from employees
where full_name like 'K%'
```

Neither of these worked. Can anyone tell me the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: 'neither of these worked' - they are the exact same query. What's Einstein supposed to have said about doing the same thing over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `%` works that way. [See here](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/glob-operator.php)

So, `'K%'` just brings all `full_name` that start with K.
and `'%K'` brings all `full_name` that end with K.

What you need is `'% K%'`, test it please.

> MySQL LIKE operator checks whether a specific character string matches
>   a specified pattern.
>
> The **LIKE** operator does a pattern matching comparison. The operand to
>   the right of the **LIKE** operator contains the pattern and the left hand
>   operand contains the string to match against the pattern. A percent
>   symbol **("%")** in the **LIKE** pattern matches any sequence of zero or more
>   characters in the string. An underscore **("_")** in the **LIKE** pattern
>   matches any single character in the string. Any other character
>   matches itself or its lower/upper case equivalent (i.e.
>   case-insensitive matching). (A bug: SQLite only understands
>   upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. The LIKE operator is
>   case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the
>   ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ'
>   LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE.)

Comment: You got it. Thank you for the docs and the answer. Will check mark your answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query:

```
select * from table where full_name like '% K%'
```